# OCaml recursive function to apply a function n times

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to create a function of type int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a in OCaml that takes an int n (non-neg) and a function f 'a -> 'a and an argument a of type 'a. f should be called on a n times.

I've tried 3 different things but can only get int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b, here are a few things I've tried.

```
let rec f n g a = 
g a;
f (n-1) g a;;
```

which gives

```
val f : int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
```

and I've tried

```
    let rec f n g a =
  if n > 0 then f (n-1) g a
  else g a
  ;;
```

which gave me

```
val f : int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

The second is closer but I'm at a loss for how to get int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about what you are trying to do. I guess it is the function below:

```
let rec foldi i f acc =
    if i <= 0 then acc else foldi (pred i) f (f acc)
```

which recursively apply `i` times the function `f` to a value `acc` and then to its its result. `foldi` might not be the best name for it though.

Comment: what exactly is pred i in your code? it appears to decrement by one?

Comment: `pred` is the dual of `succ`, it returns the predecessor of its (integral) argument, ie. that value minus one.

Comment: yes, your guess is correct. It is defined in the `Pervasives` module.

Comment: It may seem odd to have functions defined for such trivial operations, but since they come up pretty often, it's actually quite handy.

Comment: Oh I realize that, I'm moderately familiar with java and I enjoy my i++ ; i--  etc.

Comment: These operators have analog in OCaml too : `incr` and `decr`.

Answer (score 2):

The type will straighten out once you get the function written correctly. The problem with your second attempt is that it gives the wrong answer for `f5 0 ...`. It seems to me you don't want to apply the function at all in that case.

Maybe the following example will show what I mean:

```
# let add1 x = x + 1;;
val add1 : int -> int = <fun>
# f5 2 add1 3;;
- : int = 5
# f5 1 add1 3;;
- : int = 4
# f5 0 add1 3;;
- : int = 3
#
```

These are the answers you *should* get, it seems to me.

Comment: replacing > with >= doesn't seem to help. Is that the correct operator for greather than/equal to or is my error elsewhere?

Comment: Your error is elsewhere. You need to have a case that does nothing to the argument. There's no case like that in your code. (You can see the solution in didierc's answer if you want to peek.)

Comment: Thank you for the help once again, I admit I did peek though.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let rec f n g a =
> if n > 0 then f (n-1) g a
> else g a
> ;;
> ```

This is almost it, but you have to understand more your problem, and maybe just the definition of f^n. you can define f^n by : for all x, f^n(x) = f^(n-1)(f(x)), and f^0(x) = x

In your code, you have f (n-1) g a, which is f^(n-1)(x) with my notations. You are never applying f, only at the end.

The solution is :
f (n-1) g (g a) !!!

You have to apply g every time.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to write a working version minutes ago:

```
let rec applyn n func arg =
if n <= 0 then
    arg
else
    applyn (n-1) func (func arg)
```

Notice the function application happens each time when the recursive call is made. In your code, g is called only once; OCaml can't infer it to be 'a -> 'a, so gives 'a -> 'b.