# OCaml apply anonymous function without argument n-times?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

> How would I go about applying a function n-times in OCaml if I don't
>   know the functions argument?
>
> [image: n-times]
>
> I want the call `iter(n, fun x -> 2+x) 0` to evaluate to `2*n` since
>   that would be the same as `2+2+2+2...`. Also, if `n=0` it should
>   return the identity function.

My attempt:

```
let rec iter : int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int)
= fun (n,f) ->
if n = 0 then f
else iter((n-1), f( f () ))
```

Possible duplicate: [OCaml recursive function to apply a function n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285386/ocaml-recursive-function-to-apply-a-function-n-times) but this question has an argument for the anonymous function so the answers does not help me.

Comment: But you say that you want the function to be the identity function in case `n` is zero.

Comment: @Onsem as far as I understand the identity function is the function I provide as an argument

Comment: "*Also, if n=0 it should return the identity function.*". It is in the homework assignment :)

Comment: What you have right now is exponentiation instead of multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not “have an argument” right now, but since the result is a function you can always just bring an argument in scope by returning a lambda:

```ml
let rec iter : int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int)
     = fun (n,f) ->
        if n = 0 then f
                 else fun x -> iter(n-1, f) (f x);;
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv@YqhICSaitWbpZ49@gtSdjEQt6VGyN/HbL30NAw783am8fmOpURKWGhESLTgiiAJe1iV9qbOqW69GcBfgRXPejOBIRhwQnqRgA3FD/0Tee0q2ErbedS8ZWTX9@WxVBQf51XQ3CnGCbvQ1E@6w178FpEPncNZez8)</sup>

Note that, as Willem remarks, your base case is probably wrong: for `n=0`, you want to return the identity function *regardless* of what function is passed in. Otherwise you get strange behaviour, for instance such a function should generally fulfill `iter (n, fun x -> x+1) 0 ≡ n`, but with your base case it gives `n+1`.

I would write the function thus:

```ml
let rec iter : int -> ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a)
   = fun n f x -> if n = 0
                     then x
                     else iter (n-1) f (f x);;
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LCgIxDLz7FcOCbIqs@Li5rGeP/kJZUizErtQK/fua1pNoLpNkMpNZZnuXUoQTIs/wiSNO8CFhOIN6W6G35ntaAZjgXgEBDrluvdN@wq5Sv5VuHJD/cyxP/vylMOyNGpJ6mnEs16g53PbRAN2FRRasfQdq50c91AiUW7q8Ue2hyt4)</sup>

Here I've not explicitly mentioned the identity function, but because I just return `x` when `n` is zero, that's what the identity function does. Alternatively, you can return another lambda which just passes the argument through:

```ml
let rec iter : int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
      = fun n f ->
          if n = 0
           then fun x -> x   (* identity function *)
           else fun x -> iter (n-1) f (f x);;
```

Comment: Very helpful. Where can I find out what an identity function is?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if this is what you want - a small modification of the answer you linked to seems to do the job though:

*Edit: identity function depends on the nature of the function you pass to iter (right?), so I am not really sure how you can get it just from looking at f. That's why I am only returning f for now. And repeat `fun x -> x + 2` n times - wouldn't that give you `x + 2 * n`?

```
let iter n f =
    let chain_func f1 f2 arg = f1 (f2 arg) in
    let rec aux n f newf = 
         if n <= 0 then newf else aux (n - 1) f ( chain_func f newf ) in
    aux (n - 1) f f;;
```

*Edit 2: identity function is `fun x -> x` so the last line needs to be fixed to: `aux n f (fun x -> x)`